# Update the Lookup list

Tags: lookup, lookup-filter

I have create a lookup from Account to an account. I need to display only the accounts with which are accessed by portal user. For this scenario, i have created a trigger on user, when user get inserted get the contact id and update the contact field partner user (this is a custom field i create for this scenario). Now i need to display list on lookup only the Account whose contact partner user field is true. Please guide me is what need to be done to get this process working or anything i need to change to get the solution.

Comment: What is the default sharing on Account for the org?

Answer (score 0):

I recall your previous questions related to this and I also recall you were wanting to list accounts with contacts who were portal users. Its not clear to me from the phrasing of your current question if you want accounts related to a specific portal user or to all accounts which have contacts who are portal users. Those are two very different questions and the 1st one wouldn't have required you to add the additional field.

I'm going to assume you want all accounts that have portal users. If so, I believe you'll need to create a query that will look something like this:

```
 <Account>acct = [SELECT ID, Name, Contact.partner_user__r FROM Account WHERE select Contact.partner_user__r = : 'true' ]
```

The problem with the above is that it could return multiple instances of the same account. Note the use of `__r` instead of `__c` If that's the case, you may want to add a `GroupBy ID` clause. I'm also assuming `partner_user__c` was what you named the custom field and that it was added to `Contacts`, in which case, you may need to do a subselect to make this work and then sort the results.

I may be slightly off on the syntax as normally I'd be doing something like this from a trigger and would have already collected a set of contacts who met the criteria.

Comment: Is it possible on Standard lookup.

Comment: I somehow don't think so. I believe you'll need to create a controller extension that will return the results of the query to you. I do very little VF except creating custom PDF quote generators/controllers. For guidance, I recommend you look at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_intro.htm?language=en and the last section of https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apex_workbook.meta/apex_workbook/apex_workbook.htm as references.